# React-Native header animating separately to View when Modal shows

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I have a basic React Native application (built using expo) that has a primary "Home" view with a navigation bar, and a modal that displays as a sheet on top of the screen.

When the sheet animates in, the navigation bar animates up and off the screen (rather than animating down with its parent container). When the sheet is dismissed, the navigation animates in from the side.

I've attached a video link so you can see what it looks like in action.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1a4Wk.jpg

And this is the start of my navigation stack which shows the two views (Questionnaire being the sheet).

````
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home"
      screenOptions={({ route }) => {
        return {
          cardOverlayEnabled: true,
        };
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeView} />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Questionnaire"
        component={QuestionnaireView}
        options={({ route }) => {
          return {
            headerShown: false,
            gestureEnabled: true,
            cardOverlayEnabled: true,
            ...TransitionPresets.ModalPresentationIOS,
          };
        }}
      />```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the screen with the modal sheet in another stack in the same level of your Home Stack Navigator

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/modal/#creating-a-modal-stack

[image: modal stack purpose]